# URI Online Judge | 1030 Flavious Josephus Legend

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, adhoc

Sorry for bother everyone. I got a Runtime error with the codes below but nothing wrong run with my computer. I really don't know what's wrong.

Any comments will be much appreciated, thank you.

```
NC = eval(input())

for i in range(0, NC):
    n, k = map(int, input().split())
    Circle = list(range(1, n+1))

    index = k - 1
    while len(Circle) > 1:
        Circle.pop(index)
        index = index + (k - 1)
        if index >= len(Circle):
            index %= len(Circle)
    print ("Case %d: %d" % (i+1, Circle[0]))
```

[Online judge result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyyJO.png)

Comment: What "Runtime error"?

Comment: @zuazo
Thanks for your reply.

Sorry... I really don't know. It just shows "Runtime error" on the submit result but I didn't observe any error on my local side.

Comment: I saw the messages now.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 9, in <module>
    Circle.pop(index)
IndexError: pop index out of range
Command exited with non-zero status (1)`

Comment: @zuazo

Solved, thanks.

Comment: No problem, @Keysound. Always try to get a specific error message before asking a question. Most times you'll get the answer ;-)